# Windows 8 never shuts down completely

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

When I press Shutdown in Windows 8 it never shuts down completely. I changed power options in the Control panel and unchecked the fast boot option, but the problem is still there. How can I fix it?

Note:

If I disabled graphic card the screen never shutdown. It still hang with the message of windows is shutting down.
I need to press power button until it shutdown completely in both cases.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is exactly. What do you mean by *"never shuts down completely"*? Does it hibernate? Does the power light never go dark? Does it hang on the shutdown screen?

Comment: power light never go dark and battery lose all charge if it continue lighting.

Comment: When you say "Press Shutdown" do you mean the physical Power Button on your machine, or the Shutdown option in your OS?

Comment: Shutdown option in OS

Answer (score 1):

try this solution

try this solution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udZvEG2vPf0

Comment: I tried to uncheck fast boot but the problem still existed. Thank you sana

Comment: please tell a short description of what is happening in the video in case the video gets taken down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried shutting down using the CMD prompt, which you would run as Admin?

in Windows 8 and up, Windows uses a "hybrid shutdown" which holds some operating system functions in memory even after your PC has been shut down. Allegedly this speeds up shutdown and power on. This can cause problems under certain circumstances, however.

Overcome this by using the CMD below:

shutdown /s /t 0

(the /s part tells the PC to power down completely the /t 0 part tells the shutdown to begin immediately)

Comment: I have recently installed windows7 and this problem still happened. I write your command shutdown /s /t 0 in command prompt, it shutdown the screen only and the power light still working and fans also working

Comment: If I disabled graphic card the screen never turns off and still working with the message off windiws is shuttingdown so I press the power button until it turnoff comletely.